# Angular Dynamically loaded Feature Module using Feature Route

Tags: angular

I’m working on an Angular plugin solution where the plugin is loaded and the component is rendered in a router-outlet. Specifically, the plugin uses SystemJs to dynamically load from the Eggshell as follows:

```
loadPlugin(pluginName: string) {
    this.pluginLoader.load(pluginName).then(moduleFactory => {
      const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);
      const entryComponent = (moduleFactory.moduleType as any).entry;
      const compFactory = moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
        entryComponent
      );
      this.vcRef.createComponent(compFactory);

      // Debugging of router
      const rootRoutes = this.injector.get(ROUTES);
      const featureRoutes = moduleRef.injector.get(ROUTES);

    });
  }
}
```

The “Root" router is used to invoke the loadPlugin function, thus placing the ConfigComponent within the Eggshells `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. This all works as expected.

The plugin consists of ConfigModule, which contains a feature route as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'widget', component: WidgetComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ConfigComponent,
    WidgetComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    ConfigComponent,
    WidgetComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    WidgetComponent,
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class ConfigModule {
  static entry = ConfigComponent;
}
```

Where the config template contains the following:
`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

The issue is that the widget route cannot be found, when a routerLink is invoked within the ConfigComponent. The debug statements in the loadPlugin show that the feature route exists when the ConfigComponent is rendered.

My only guess is that, the AppModule (which references the root route) doesn't contain an import to the ConfigModule. But, not sure if that really is the issue or how exactly the root and feature routes get combined to make that happen. Any ideas are certainly welcomed...

Answer (score 0):

So, it's no different than lazy loading and having feature routes. I had to add a default route to the forChild route:

> const routes: Routes = [
>         { path: '', component: ConfigComponent },
>         { path: 'widget', component: WidgetComponent }
>       ];
>   In other words, the path in the Root Router has already been set to "Config" making it already within the ConfigComponent's context.